# this is from npm selfcore , this script is good for 2 hours and then stop working without errors... how can I resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js

this script is  good for 2 hours and then stop working without errors... how can I resolve

```
import selfcore from "selfcore";
const client = new selfcore('Token')
const gateway = new selfcore.Gateway('Token');
gateway.on("message",(m) => {
    if(m.channel_id  === ""){
    let content = m.content ? m.content : {embeds : [m.embeds[0]]};
    client.sendWebhook("URL",m.channel_id + content);
    };
    
});
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code here.  Include the code in your question, as actual text.

Comment: Might be because you eventually try to set hours to a negative number, idk how javascript handles that

Comment: @RobertHarvey sorry about that

Comment: @Samathingamajig sorry man I forgot to delete my old code that part   "var d = new Date();  d.setHours(d.getHours() - 2)  " it's unrelated